# How do I safely delete old kernel versions in CentOS 7?

Tags: centos, kernel, linux-kernel

I might be encountering odd symptoms resulting from competing kernels in CentOS 7.  So how do I safely delete the old kernels?  And how do I know which kernel is the newest one?

Below is the terminal output I get at the moment when researching this on the server in question.  Note that I tried package-cleanup but it leaves the same 2 kernels:

[The instructions in this tutorial](http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2010/install-virtualbox-with-yum-on-fedora-centos-red-hat-rhel/) say that the output of the following two commands should match, but you can see that they do not match, even after a reboot:

```
[root@localhost ~]# rpm -qa kernel |sort -V |tail -n 1
kernel-3.10.0-229.el7.x86_64
[root@localhost ~]# uname -r
3.10.0-229.14.1.el7.x86_64
```

The remaining commands confirm that there are two kernels, and illustrate attempts to delete the old one.

```
[root@localhost ~]# cd /usr/src/kernels
[root@localhost kernels]# ls -al
total 16
drwxr-xr-x.  4 root root 4096 Oct  2 12:55 .
drwxr-xr-x.  4 root root 4096 Oct  2 13:15 ..
drwxr-xr-x. 22 root root 4096 Oct  2 12:55 3.10.0-229.14.1.el7.x86_64
drwxr-xr-x. 22 root root 4096 Oct  2 12:35 3.10.0-229.el7.x86_64
[root@localhost kernels]# rpm -q kernel
kernel-3.10.0-229.el7.x86_64
kernel-3.10.0-229.14.1.el7.x86_64
[root@localhost kernels]# package-cleanup --oldkernels=1
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Usage: 
    package-cleanup: helps find problems in the rpmdb of system and correct them

    usage: package-cleanup --problems or --leaves or --orphans or --oldkernels
Command line error: --oldkernels option does not take a value
[root@localhost kernels]# package-cleanup --oldkernels
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
No old kernels to remove
[root@localhost kernels]# rpm -q kernel
kernel-3.10.0-229.el7.x86_64
kernel-3.10.0-229.14.1.el7.x86_64
[root@localhost kernels]#
```

I also opened up `/etc/yum.conf` and set `installonly_limit=1`, but this resulted in an error from a subsequent `yum update` command saying that 1 is outside the range of acceptable values for `installonly_limit`.

I assume that `3.10.0-229.14.1.el7.x86_64` is the newest, but how can I know this?  Also, the boot options seem to offer multiple kernels to choose from.  And the opportunities for confusion get worse when the system auto-boots from the first kernel on the list of options.

**Can someone please explain how this works, and in specific, how to safely delete old kernels so that kernel version can be eliminated as a possible cause of odd symptoms?**  I want to make sure that the most recent kernel is the only kernel that can ever run, no matter how the system is restarted.

Comment: Walking out the door so I can't write up a full answer right now. Will try to check back later. yum-utils used to do this (not sure if it still does). http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2012/delete-remove-old-kernels-on-fedora-centos-red-hat-rhel/

Comment: @0xSheepdog Yes, I am using those commands from a similar tutorial, but the CentOS 7 server will not allow `installonly_limit=1`.  I am getting funny symptoms that might be resulting from two kernel versions, so I would like to have only one version, if possible, or at least to have a definitive explanation of why it is not possible to have less than 2 versions, if in fact it is not possible.

Comment: I would suggest changing your "keep" criteria to "booted kernel" as opposed to simply newest -- for various reasons, you may not be booting to the newest kernel.

Answer (score 32):

`package-cleanup --oldkernels --count=1` delete all kernels except latest.

Comment: Thanks Fractal Turtle for brief answer. I also want to you to safely keep at least two latest kernel. `package-cleanup --oldkernels --count=2`

Comment: I run `package-cleanup --oldkernels --count=1`. After reboot, I still get two kernels: `CentOS Linux (4.4.6-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64) 7 (Core)` and `CentOS Linux (3.10.0-514.2.2.el7.x86_64) 7 (Core)`, do you know how to just keep one?

Comment: Can someone answer @Ron 's question?

Comment: fyi, **package-cleanup** is part of: `yum install yum-utils`

Comment: This solution no longer works with Centos 8 onwards. Gives the error message `package-cleanup has to be executed with one of the options: --dupes, --leaves, --orphans, --problems or --cleandupes` Refer my answer below for a working solution for Centos 8.

Answer (score 14):

### RHEL and CentOS >= 8 (and Fedora with DNF).

RHEL 8+ use a new package manager (DNF / yum 4, see [yum2dnf](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/yum2dnf.8.html)), which recommend:

```
dnf remove $(dnf repoquery --installonly --latest-limit=-2)
```

`--latest-limit=-2` means to leave two last versions - current and the previous one;

`--latest-limit=-1` will remove all except current one.

There's also `yum remove --oldinstallonly` to remove old installonly packages, not just kernels (?).

(this command requires dnf `>= 4.2.17-4` [bug #1774670](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1774670))

### Older RHEL and CentOS ( <=7 )

The command `package-cleanup` was used to remove older kernel with yum <4. Use `--count=1` to keep just the latest. The program will never remove the kernel currently used ("Not removing kernel 3.10.0-327.el7 because it is the running kernel"), so you may end-up with two kernels in /boot... until you reboot and re-run the command.

So the command is

```
package-cleanup --oldkernels --count=1
```

The manpage document three options:

```
--oldkernels
          Remove old kernel and kernel-devel packages.
--count <COUNT>
          Number of duplicate/kernel packages to keep on the system (default 2)
--keepdevel
          Do not remove kernel-devel packages when removing kernels
```

Comment: This solution no longer works with Centos 8 onwards. Gives the error message `package-cleanup has to be executed with one of the options: --dupes, --leaves, --orphans, --problems or --cleandupes` Refer my answer below for a working solution for Centos 8.

Answer (score 5):

For Centos 8 onwards (Yum version 4) you can use the command

```
yum remove --oldinstallonly
```

This removes all old versions of the kernel. Use when you want to have only the latest release version of the kernel.

Answer (score 1):

Use `yum upgrade` instead of `yum update`

Then it will only keep three kernels. If you use `update` then it will fill up your `/boot`

Answer (score -3):

according to [this](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-remove-old-unused-kernels-on-centos-linux):

run `rpm -q kernel` to show installed kernel

then run `yum remove kernel <shown kernel from output above>` to remove the kernel

reboot ur computer

edit:
this actualy work for @Ron's problem, but make sure elrepo kernel is running correctly

Comment: How do  you avoid removing your current kernel?

Comment: IDK specific command for that @JeffSchaller
I guess, to make sure u are not removing current kernel, u sud check it first by using `uname -r` then delete the unused kernel but shown from that command,