# Is it safe to remove these kernel files in /boot?

Tags: centos, kernel, yum

I have one kernel installed currently, `3.10.0-327.28.3`.

In my /boot directly, I have what looks like a lot of stuff that `package-cleanup` perhaps missed:

```
    -rw-r--r--  1 root root  17M Aug 28 18:00 initramfs-3.10.0-327.10.1.el7.x86_64.img
    -rw-r--r--  1 root root  17M Aug 28 18:00 initramfs-3.10.0-327.28.2.el7.x86_64.img
    -rw-r--r--  1 root root  20M Aug 29 00:46 initramfs-3.10.0-327.28.3.el7.x86_64.img
    -rw-r--r--  1 root root  17M Aug 28 17:00 initramfs-3.10.0-327.28.3.el7.x86_64kdump.img
    -rw-r--r--  1 root root  17M Aug 28 18:01 initramfs-3.10.0-327.4.5.el7.x86_64.img
```

Can I remove those 3 files safely?   They look like they belong to older kernels.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/233597/how-do-i-safely-delete-old-kernel-versions-in-centos-7

Comment: @user4556274 `package-cleanup` is ignoring these files for some reason.

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the above mentioned question as it regards files left over by the solutions suggested there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Those files are from previous kernel installation. You may had upgraded kernel hence old kernel files along with their initramfs files are residing on /boot partition.

If you want to clean up them then you can remove by using distribution-specific utility like apt-get.

Once you remove, then execute the following command to remove those kernel's entry from `grub.cfg` file

`grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg`

if you have legacy grub installed then modify the `/boot/grub/grub.conf` file manually.

Comment: Is it harmful just to delete the files and not change the grub config file?

Comment: In case your system is using `grub2` issue this command: `grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg`