# Remove all kernel packages except the currently used one

Tags: ubuntu, centos, linux-kernel, apt, package-management

How can I automatically delete all other kernels which I'm not using?

So, here's my situation:

- Using different versions of Ubuntu / CentOS
- Automatic updates were on -> Linux downloaded many new kernel versions
- Now I want to delete all other kernel versions, except the one I'm currently using

Code:

```
#find out current kernel version:
uname -r

#check which versions are downloaded to computer
dpkg --get-selections | grep linux-image

#delete desired kernel
sudo apt-get purge [KERNEL]

#autoremove
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

There can be easily more than 15 kernels in one linux, and I have more than 50 linuxes which I have to go through.

Comment: Check the second answer on this post: https://askubuntu.com/questions/2793/how-do-i-remove-old-kernel-versions-to-clean-up-the-boot-menu I think that is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

On Ubuntu you can use `purge-old-kernels` to purge old kernels , to install it:

For ubuntu 16.04

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys F430BBA5
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:byobu/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install byobu
```

Also you can install it without adding the `ppa`: `sudo apt-get install byobu`

For Ubuntu versions lower than 16.04

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bikeshed/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install bikeshed
```

Run the following command to keeping the latest 2 kernel :

```
sudo purge-old-kernels
```

You can specify the number `n` of kernel to keep:

```
sudo purge-old-kernels --keep n
```

`n=1`:

```
sudo purge-old-kernels --keep 1
```

---

On centOS install `yum-utils` package :

```
yum install yum-utils
```

To keep the latest `n` kernels , run:

```
package-cleanup --oldkernels --count=n
```

`n=1`:

```
package-cleanup --oldkernels --count=1
```

Comment: The Centos no longer works with Centos 8 onwards. Gives the error message `package-cleanup has to be executed with one of the options: --dupes, --leaves, --orphans, --problems or --cleandupes` Refer my answer below for a working solution for Centos 8

Answer (score 2):

For Centos 8 onwards you can use the command:

```
dnf remove --oldinstallonly
```

This removes all old versions of the kernel. Use when you want to have **only the latest** release version of the kernel installed.

My original answer at: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/628434/145515

Answer (score 1):

Be aware, this command removes all kernel images and headers of major release 4, but not the running one.

```
apt purge $(dpkg-query -W -f='${binary:Package}\n' 'linux-image-4*' 'linux-headers-4*' | grep -v $(uname -r))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below command. Before you execute apt-get purge, just double check the output of your grep to not contain your current kernel version

```
dpkg --list | grep linux-image | awk '{print $2}' | grep -v linux-image-`uname -r` | xargs apt-get purge
```