# Linux kernel on my centos 8 server is filling up /boot partition

Tags: linux, centos, kernel, linux-kernel, cloud

I am having this issue in my instance where /boot partition is getting full . I would like to remove the old kernels that are in my instance to clean up the /boot partition. However, when I run this command to get the active kernel version, I get this.

```
uname -r 
5.4.17-2136.308.9.el8uek.x86_64
```

when I list all installed kernels with this following command, I get these three kernels. Why is kernel-5.4.17-2136.308.9.el8uek.x86_64 not being listed in the rpm -qa kernel command?

```
   rpm -qa kernel
kernel-4.18.0-372.9.1.el8.x86_64
kernel-4.18.0-348.23.1.el8_5.x86_64
kernel-4.18.0-372.13.1.0.1.el8_6.x86_64
```

Answer (score 1):

> Why is kernel-5.4.17-2136.308.9.el8uek.x86_64 not being listed in the rpm -qa kernel command?

Because `rpm -qa kernel` matches only packages named `kernel`, based on the `el8uek` dist tag your kernel is [Unbreakable Enterprise Kernel](https://docs.oracle.com/en/operating-systems/uek/) from Oracle Linux and is from a package called `kernel-uek` so to list it you need to use `rpm -qa "kernel*"`.

If you just want to remove old kernels you can use DNF to do that automatically, see for example [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/269095/196468) for details (but you might want to simply remove all "kernel" packages if you want to use only the UEK kernel).

Comment: does this require a reboot  @VojtechTrefny

Comment: No, if you don't want to switch to a different kernel.

Comment: Thank you! that did it!

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem a lot on old CentOS, this should still work, although it does not answer your question about why rpm is not showing the current kernel:

As root in a terminal do:

```
package-cleanup --oldkernel --count=2
```

Then reboot. Your /boot will not be full after this.

You might as well go ahead after and do:

```
yum update && yum upgrade && reboot
```

Comment: There is no package-cleanup in CentOS 8. Theoretically you can use dnf (dnf remove --oldinstallonly --setopt installonly_limit=2 kernel) but it does seem to ignore the package limit

Comment: Yes @Dan, this was for CenOS 6,7. It is interesting that they get rid of package-cleanup but not the issue :) Thanks for the input.